# Could we clone/copy an object which is an instance of Outlook.NameSpace?

Tags: c#, copy, clone

I want to clone/copy an object from another which is an instance of Outlook.Namespace interface . I investigated **ICloneable Interface**. There are Shallow and Deep Cloning solutions to clone/copy an object. They are useful for classes which are known all attributes. But, with the as Outlook.Namespace, I don't know what the attribute () how to clone its.

Would you give me some advice about that? Thank so much.
The code bellows to get email address of a contact in Outlook. And I want to clone **otl** object at line `Outlook.NameSpace otl`

```
private static string GetEmailAddress(Outlook.NameSpace otl, string email, string emailtype, ref int nCount)
    {   
        string sEmailIn = email;

        Recipient rcp = null;
        try
        {
            rcp = otl.CreateRecipient(email);                
            rcp.Resolve();
            if (rcp.Resolved)
            {
                AddressEntry address = rcp.AddressEntry;
                ExchangeUser user = address.GetExchangeUser();
                email = user.PrimarySmtpAddress;
                if (address != null)
                {
                    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(address);
                }
                if (user != null)
                {
                    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(user);
                }
                ++nCount;
            }
        }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {
            ShoreTrace.TraceLn("Exception while converting email: " + sEmailIn);
            ShoreTrace.TraceLn("Content " + ex);
            ShoreTrace.TraceLn("Resulting email: " + email);
            return sEmailIn;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (rcp != null)
            {
                Marshal.ReleaseComObject(rcp);
            }

        }
        return email;
    }
```

--------  UPDATE ----------

I debug and watch the otl object's value  , you can see the image below. I wonder that we can use the foreach loop to browse through all the properties of it. Then reassigned to an object of the same type. See code below and rise you opinion
[image]

*Note: Please, Open image in new tap to see more clearly.*

```
public static object Clone(object obj)
    {
        object new_obj = Activator.CreateInstance(obj.GetType());
        foreach (PropertyInfo pi in obj.GetType().GetProperties())
        {
            if (pi.CanRead && pi.CanWrite && pi.PropertyType.IsSerializable)
            {
                pi.SetValue(new_obj, pi.GetValue(obj, null), null);
            }
        }
        return new_obj;
    }
```

Comment: What is `rpt` and why do you want to clone that object?

Comment: If objects in a library don't offer means to clone them, then you are probably not supposed to do so

Comment: @Carsten: That is otl not rpt. So sorry, my error. Why I want to clone it? Because the code following hold resources of outlook: rcp = otl.CreateRecipient outlook (email); rcp.Resolve (); When rcp.Resolve() method called every time, outlook will be delay about 100ms. The problem will be serious when Outlook has a large number of contacts. So I want to free up Outlook resources by cloning an object.

Comment: `Outlook.Namespace` is just a .NET object to access the underlying COM object of Outlook. I'm afraid there is no way you can make a copy or clone of that COM object.

Answer (score 0):

Below `solution` is `generic` ... But it only work if the `class` is `serializable`

```
        /// <summary>
        /// Only applicable for serializable object
        /// Makes a copy from the object.
        /// Doesn't copy the reference memory, only data.
        /// </summary>
        /// <typeparam name="T">Type of the return object.</typeparam>
        /// <param name="item">Object to be copied.</param>
        /// <returns>Returns the copied object.</returns>
        public static T Clone<T>(this T item)
        {
            if (item != null)
            {
                BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
                MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();

                formatter.Serialize(stream, item);
                stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

                T result = (T)formatter.Deserialize(stream);

                stream.Close();

                return result;
            }
            else
                return default(T);
        }
```